# Why gradle not creating local repository and downloading same dependencies for every project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm using Gradle with Java Project in IntelliJ Idea. 
I see that Gradle downloading dependencies for first time on opening project.
But there is another project with same dependencies then also it's **re-downloading those libs**. why?

Why doesn't it maintain Maven like local repository even after configured?

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

How can Gradle maintain local repository and next it should first check local repo and go for download if no matching dependencies found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that piece of code you instruct gradle to look at the local maven repository, then at the central maven repository and last in JCenter when looking for dependencies. The first one it finds your dependency it takes it from.

It does not instruct Gradle to put resolved dependencies to the local maven repository though. This is e. g. helpful if you have two projects in two separate builds, one depends on the other and you install the first dependency to the local maven repository with the respective Gradle task and then build the second one, depending on the version you just built and installed.

Gradle has a resolution cache though in `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/` where it caches all downloaded dependencies and also reuses this from different builds.

Comment: Understood. But how configure Gradle to maintain Local Repo for all downloaded dependencies in different projects. like maven does. Thanks.

Comment: It just does, as I explained in the last paragraph of my answer. No need to do anything special.